# Navigate From Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment to Fragment - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

As a newbie i am struggling with a problem. My problem is;

In First Fragment, when user click a button a bottom sheet dialog fragment shows up and this dialog fragment have a button to go to Second Fragment. But i couldn't find a way to navigate between fragments by clicking a button in dialog fragment. I tried somethings that i found on the google but didn't worked for me. I am using Navigation safe args to navigate between fragments. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here the sample code for you I hope this work you

```
           var bottomSheetDialog:BottomSheetDialog?=null
           var handler:Handler?=null
            bottomSheetDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
                val parentView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_offer, null)
                bottomSheetDialog?.setContentView(parentView)
                val image= parentView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
                val btn :MaterialButton = parentView.findViewById(R.id.claim_offer)
                btn.setOnClickListener {
                      findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_rewardsFragment)
                }
    
                handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
                handler?.postDelayed({
                    bottomSheetDialog?.show()
                }, 5000)
```

Comment: Where should i add this code? I tried but it did not worked.

Comment: in your fragment!!??Can you share me your code  how you have implemented